# ADF parsing object parameter json errors

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a linked service for an on-prem SQL Server with a parameter of type Object named **ConnectionDetails**.

When I try using the test connection button using the following input json for **ConnectionDetails** I get parsing errors:

```json
{
    "ServerName" : "myserver.test.com",
    "DatabaseName" : "mydb",
    "UserName" : "myuser",
    "UserPasswordAKV" : "mypass-secret"
}

The parameters and expression cannot be resolved for schema operations. 

Error Message: {
    "Message": "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: S. Path 'typeProperties.connectionString', line 19, position 69."
}
```

I tried these as my expressions:

```
@linkedService().ConnectionDetails.ServerName
@linkedService().ConnectionDetails.DatabaseName
@linkedService().ConnectionDetails.UserName
```

Linked Service JSON:

```json
    {
        "name": "SqlServer_OnPrem_Dynamic2",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
        "properties": {
            "description": "",
            "parameters": {
                "ConnectionDetails": {
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "annotations": [],
            "type": "SqlServer",
            "typeProperties": {
                "connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Data Source=@{linkedService().ConnectionDetails.ServerName};Initial Catalog=@{linkedService().ConnectionDetails.DatabaseName};User ID=@{linkedService().ConnectionDetails.UserName}",
                "password": {
                    "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                    "store": {
                        "referenceName": "keys_dev",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "secretName": {
                        "value": "@{linkedService().ConnectionDetails.UserPasswordAKV}",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong I didn't think I needed to use any other function for this.

Comment: which kind database did you use? Where did you set the expressions? Can you show us any screenshots?

Comment: @Leon Yue I updated the original post with more info.  I should mention this connection works fine when I use simple string parameters instead of a json object

Comment: I agree with you. I tested String and Object type of parameter, they all get the error. But I get the error "Unexpected end of JSON input". I speculate that json data type is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, object type parameter can't work. You can try to create four string type parameters to have a try.

[image]

Comment: Any ideas why it would not work? I mean with the "object" type being available in the drop down and all.